# Ionic navigate to another page on new browser tab

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to use a link to navigate to another page of my app but I need it to open on a new browser tab.

The link in my html looks like this:

```
<a (click)="goToPage(item.id)">{{item.id}}</a>
```

And at the moment I am handling the navigation like this:

```
goToPage(id: string) {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot("MyPage",  {
    'id': id
  });
}
```

Is there a way to adapt this to make it navigate to "MyPage" but in another browser tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way to do it with Ionic's NavController and I needed this only for web and not mobile, I ended up doing it this way:

```
goToPage(id: string) {
 var host = window.location.href;
 window.open(this.host.replace("old-page", "new-page") + "/" + id, '_blank');
}
```

It isn't the most elegant way but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In ionic you are always in the main browser tab. There is away to push and pop the navigation stack, you could see the documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

If you need some other external content within the App, you should try the InAppBrowser Plugin. But be aware on iOS about the Restrictions of App Store Release guidelines.